# Copy to clipboard multiple items

Tags: jquery, html, css, copy, clipboard

I am doing a copy to clipboard however it is only picking up the first ID. Which I understand is because you can't have multiple ID's however when i change the code to `document.getElementsByClassName` it doesn't work?

Following is my code

```
 function CopyToClipboard() {
        var input = document.getElementById("toClipboard");
        var textToClipboard = input.value;

        var success = true;
        if (window.clipboardData) { // Internet Explorer
            window.clipboardData.setData("Text", textToClipboard);
        }
        else {
            // create a temporary element for the execCommand method
            var forExecElement = CreateElementForExecCommand(textToClipboard);

            /* Select the contents of the element
                (the execCommand for 'copy' method works on the selection) */
            SelectContent(forExecElement);

            var supported = true;

            // UniversalXPConnect privilege is required for clipboard access in Firefox
            try {
                if (window.netscape && netscape.security) {
                    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
                }

                // Copy the selected content to the clipboard
                // Works in Firefox and in Safari before version 5
                success = document.execCommand("copy", false, null);
            }
            catch (e) {
                success = false;
            }

            // remove the temporary element
            document.body.removeChild(forExecElement);
        }

        if (success) {
            alert("The text is on the clipboard");
        }
        else {
            alert("Your browser doesn't allow clipboard access!");
        }
    }

    function CreateElementForExecCommand(textToClipboard) {
        var forExecElement = document.createElement("div");
        // place outside the visible area
        forExecElement.style.position = "absolute";
        forExecElement.style.left = "-10000px";
        forExecElement.style.top = "-10000px";
        // write the necessary text into the element and append to the document
        forExecElement.textContent = textToClipboard;
        document.body.appendChild(forExecElement);
        // the contentEditable mode is necessary for the  execCommand method in Firefox
        forExecElement.contentEditable = true;

        return forExecElement;
    }

    function SelectContent(element) {
        // first create a range
        var rangeToSelect = document.createRange();
        rangeToSelect.selectNodeContents(element);

        // select the contents
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(rangeToSelect);
    }
```

and here is my html;

```
<div id="App-Details"><span>Activation Guid</span><br /><br />
<input id="toClipboard" value="@appDetails.ActivationGuid"> <button onclick='CopyToClipboard ()'>Copy Guid</button></div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work when `textToClipboard` contains newline '\n'. It also collapses multiple spaces into one.

Example:

```
'Not\nworking   at all    '
```

becomes:

```
'Not working at all'
```

This is a significant data loss.

We need a good solution for browsers that don't support both `window.clipboardData` & `navigator.clipboard`. Here is my improved solution (tested on various browsers):

```js
function CopyTextareaToClipboard(textToClipboard) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textArea.value = textToClipboard;
  textArea.style.top = "0";
  textArea.style.left = "0";
  textArea.style.position = "fixed";

  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();
  textArea.select();

  bool success = true;
  try {
    if (document.execCommand('copy'))
      Alert('Successfully copied to clipboard');
    else {
      success = false;
      Alert('Something went wrong with copy command');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Alert('Something went wrong with copy: ' + e);
    success = false;
  }
  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
  return success;
}
function CopyTextToClipboard (textToClipboard) {    
    if (window.clipboardData) { // Internet Explorer
        window.clipboardData.setData("Text", textToClipboard);
        Alert('Successfully copied to clipboard');
        return true;
    }
    if (navigator && navigator.clipboard) {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToClipboard)
        .then(function () {
          Alert('Successfully copied to clipboard');
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
          // Something went wrong with copy. Falling back on textarea trick
          CopyTextareaToClipboard(textToClipboard);
        });
        return true;
    }
    return CopyTextareaToClipboard(textToClipboard);
}
```